# don't understand facebook connect with losing its session and other strange session problems in PHP

Tags: php, facebook

really simply right? to connect to Facebook, you do this:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
      'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
));
```

and then you can do this right?

```
$fbSession = $facebook->getSession();
```

But its **sometimes** invalid and **other times** i am successful. Really trying hard to understand whats going on here.

And then there's this another problem, If i did get it valid, sometimes i will get this error: "session key invalid or no longer valid" when i try to use the access_token from the fbSession.

On the side note - i am using 2 facebook account alternatively - for development and testing purpose, not sure if alternately using them is giving me these creeps. AND this is happening to me on the FB App integration, im using an IFRAME.

Can someone please explain in details what's really going on here? the behavior is not predictable and its hard for me to troubleshoot and understand the problem.

Comment: Try use one account in one browser (ff for example) and another one in another browser (for example, chrome). You shouldn't get any problems in this case.

Comment: Which version are you running?  Is it 3.0.1 ?

Answer (score 0):

Just because you do new Facebook... does not mean you can call getSession and expect a session back. Either $_REQUEST or $_COOKIE has to be set as that is what getSession uses to figure out what to return. If either is set with the session info and it is not obviously invalid, you will get a valid session returned.

A network request is never made in getSession so it is not guaranteed to return a still valid session. It is guaranteed to return a session the client still thinks is valid, if available. You will only find out it's not valid when you try to use it. Hence the "session key invalid" error.

A simple example is if you log into an account with two browsers, and then log out on one, you are actually logged out on both browsers, but the other one has no idea until you try to make a request. Thus on the latter browser, a seemingly valid session will be returned but will fail when you try to make a request.

Also I believe you are using an outdated version of the php sdk.